# IntelliJ - Replace empty parameter logger with parameter consisting of the respective class name

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging, log4j

I need to replace the old logger declaration statements in the project, which are like

```
private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

with class name as parameter, for each respective enclosing class, for eg.

```
private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EnclosingClass.class);
```

I looked at the live template but it would not replace the existing statements. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: if you are using slf4j, you can use lombok's @Slf4j annotation which will equal to your getLogger statement

Comment: It would be a nice feature to be able to use the filename in the replaceall dialog box, but I don't think it actually exists. If it's a huge project, a little script with a sed could do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Edit | Find | Replace Structurally` to do this. Use a template like the following:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="Unnamed" text="private final static Logger $logger$ = LogManager.getLogger();&#10;" recursive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="member" search_injected="false" reformatAccordingToStyle="false" shortenFQN="false" replacement="private final static Logger $logger$ = LogManager.getLogger($class$);&#10;" case_sensitive="true">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="logger" within="" contains="" />
  <variableDefinition name="class" script="&quot;logger.containingClass.qualifiedName + &quot;.class&quot;&quot;" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

You can copy this template and invoke`Import Template from Clipboard` under the tool button in the upper right of the dialog.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. However, when I try to use this, the dialog box changes to just Structural Search. Is it IntelliJ version specific?

Comment: Update: I tried using the logic you provided for the replace structurally dialog box by using the script same as yours and it worked! Thank you

Comment: The dialog changing from replace to search is a bug that will be fixed in 2021.2.